# Acetic acid reacted with Fehling's solution

Tags: organic-oxidation

During our experiment, we reacted acetic acid solution with Fehling's solution, expecting nothing to happen. Much to our surprise, the blue faded and the solution turned reddish-brown. Has this happened to anyone  before? What might be a good explanation for this?

Comment: Are you talking about vinegar or an acetic acid solution (pure)?

Comment: @AChem acetic acid solution. I'll change the question.

Comment: The reddish-brown colour indicates copper(I)oxide which suggests your acetic acid has a reducing agent in it. Check the purity of your acetic acid.

Comment: @jphys I agree with Waylander. If the acetic acid was made by oxidizing (ethyl) alcohol, it may well have some alcohol or acetaldehyde (an intermeduate) in it. These are party time for Fehling's solution.